# $\int_1^2F(x) dx$ and $F'$ of $F(x)= \begin{pmatrix} x^3+5\\ \sin x + \frac{x^2}{x+1}\\ x\exp(x) \end{pmatrix} $

Tags: integration, derivatives

$F:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

$$F(x)=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x^3+5\\
    \sin x + \frac{x^2}{x+1}\\
  x\exp(x) 
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

How can I calculate $\int_1^2F(x) dx$ and $F'$?

Can I just integrate and derive component-wisely?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: @Jon Is the solution of $\int_1^2F(x) dx$ a "vector" with 3 entries or what?

Comment: Exactly. The exercise is just asking this.